# d3.js: binding data to existing svg. what selector.each does?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, d3.js

I have some svg on html page. I want to to bind some data on them, and add decoration element based on that data. What I think I have to do is:

```
// pseudo-code
selection = select all existing svg piece i want to decorate

var datas = selection.each( function(d,i) { // each is right? maybe selection.datum() is better?
    var data = this.(do something with the svg piece)
    return data; 
});

// add elements with the "default" chain selection.data(datas).enter().append()
```

What I noticed is that selection.each does not return something where i can find the data returned. I think this is the way, but i can't figure out what i have to do for see the binded data.

So i have to do some dirty workaround like:

```
var datas = [];
selection.each( function(d,i) { // each is right? maybe selection.datum() is better?
    var data = this.(do something with the svg piece)
    datas.push(data); 
});
```

Why? how can i do something similar without pushing manually data into an array AND binding data inside some existing svg element?

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nkint/Ga8UJ/2/).

Or, if you prefer, the code:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg>
        <rect id="0" x="0" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
        <rect id="1" x="50" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
        <rect id="2" x="100" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
        <rect id="3" x="150" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
        <rect id="4" x="200" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
        <rect id="5" x="250" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

js:

```
var svg = d3.select("#container svg"); 
var districts = svg.selectAll("rect"); 

var district_data = []; 
var _c = districts.each(function(d, i) { 
    var bbox = this.getBBox(); 
    var centroid = [
        bbox.x + bbox.width/2, 
        bbox.y + bbox.height/2
    ];
    var ret = {centroid:centroid, position:bbox.x};
    district_data.push( ret );
    return ret;
});

// now, i'm expecting that _c should be something 
// similar to district_data
console.log(_c);

svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(district_data) // i think i should use `_c` instead of manually created `district_data` but does not work
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
     .attr("class", "district_circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.centroid[0]})
     .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.centroid[1]})
     .attr("r", 10)
     .attr("fill", function(d){ return "rgb("+d.position+",0,0)"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's incorrect to expect an `each()` method to return an array of data. It's just a way to iterate over the selection. What it's returning (the thing that's getting assigned to `_c`) is a d3 selection object –– the same selection object on which you're calling `each()`. I.e. `_c == districts` evaluates to true. AFAIK, the d3 selection object doesn't provide anything that you could use to gather values the way you describe wanting to do.

Generally, you'd want to use a `.map()` function to gather those values and assign them to `_c`, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be possible here, because, again, `districts` is a d3 selection, not a flat array. And if you tried calling `map()` on it, I don't think it would actually iterate over each element in the selection, and you'll also get a js error, because the `this` object doesn't get assigned to the SVG element on which you need to call `getBBox()`.

Bottom line, I think the approach you took is the correct one: iterate with `each()` and build up the array by pushing into it.

---

I can suggest one other way to do this more concisely, but it requires modifying the structure of the existing SVG:

Instead of of having the `rects` be siblings, nest each one inside a `g`. Like:

```
<div id="container">
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect id="0" x="0" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <rect id="1" x="50" y="50" width="30" height="30"/>
  </g>
  ...
```

Then in JS (untested):

```
svg.selectAll('g')
  .each(function(d, i) { // Note, d is actually undefined, bc no data-binding was done
    var rect = d3.select(this).select('rect');
    var bbox = this.getBBox(); 
    var centroid = [
        bbox.x + bbox.width/2, 
        bbox.y + bbox.height/2
    ];

    // Now create the circle, appending it to the group,
    // as a sibling of its corresponding rect
    var circle = d3.select(this).append('circle')
     .attr("class", "district_circle")
     .attr("cx", centroid[0])
     .attr("cy", centroid[1])
     .attr("r", 10)
     .attr("fill", "rgb("+bbox.x+",0,0)");
  });
```

This is still not totally great form, because the positioning is applied to each circle and rect, whereas, ideally, the positioning would be applied at the group level –– and that's not too hard to achieve. But now we're getting picky.

Comment: nice idea! it could be handy! (really, i have to replace the circle with a pie chart, and nesting it inside the callback of selection.each() could be a smart way to do it!)

but.. why should the have be in a group? couldn't not only be `d3.select(this);`?

Comment: @nkit, yeah, maybe the grouping is not needed. You could `d3.selectAll('rect')` (working with the flat hierarchy as you have it), and then do the iterating with `each()`, like I showed, and append the circles to the same parent of the rects (i.e. the SVG itself). Stylistically, using groups is cleaner and more flexible. It allows you, at any point further down the road, to select all the groups, and iterate one by one on them, with access to the "related" rect and circle inside it.